# Why does the_title() filter is also applied in menu title?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, themes

I have created below function to hide page title. But when I execute this code, it also hides the menu name.

```
function wsits_post_page_title( $title ) {
              if( is_admin())

        return $title;

    $selected_type  =   get_option('wsits_page_show_hide');

    if(!is_array($selected_type)) return $title;

    if ( ( in_array(get_post_type(), $selected_type ) ) &&  get_option('wsits_page_show_hide') ) 
    {
        $title = '';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', array($this, 'wsits_post_page_title') );
```

Comment: Because menu items also have titles and they need to be filtered :). If this is your theme, you can remove the filter before displaying the menu and then adding it again. Alternatively you can do the opposite and add the filter only when you need it.

Comment: How would someone go about removing a filter and adding it back after displaying the menu title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nikola is correct:

> Because menu items also have titles and they need to be filtered :).

To make this only call in the posts, and not in menus, you can add a check for `in_the_loop()`  - if it is true, you're in a post.

So change the first line in the function to:

`if( is_admin() || !in_the_loop() )`

and all should be well.

Comment: @Paul This is not working for the widget containing custom menu.

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit of a hack but you can solve this by adding your action to loop_start.

```
function make_custom_title( $title, $id ) {
    // Your Code Here
}

function set_custom_title() {
   add_filter( 'the_title', 'make_custom_title', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'loop_start', 'set_custom_title' );
```

By embedding the_title filter inside of a loop_start action, we avoid overwriting the menu title attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like that :

In your `function.php` :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ze_title');
function ze_title($a) {
    global $dontTouch;
    if(!$dontTouch && !is_admin())
        $a = someChange($a);
    return $a;
}
```

In your template :

```
$dontTouch = 1;
wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'MyMenu') );
$dontTouch = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer because it was the search result I ended up clicking on while searching about targeting the filter hook `the_title` while ignoring the filter effect for navigation items.

I was working on a section in a theme which I wanted to add buttons to the page title within the heading one tag.

**It looked similar to this:**

```
<?php echo '<h1>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title ) . '</h1>'.PHP_EOL; ?>
```

**I was then "hooking in" like this:**

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_callback_function' );
```

However, the above targets literally everything which calls `the_title` filter hook, and this includes navigation items.

**I changed the filter hook definition like this:**

```
<?php echo '<h1>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title, $post->ID, true ) . '</h1>'.PHP_EOL; ?>
```

Pretty much every call to `the_title` filter passes parameter 1 as the `$post->post_title` and parameter 2 as the `$post->ID`. Search the WordPress core code for `apply_filters( 'the_title'*` and you'll see for yourself.

So I decided to add a third parameter for situations where I want to target specific items which call `the_title` filter. This way, I can still receive the benefit of all callbacks which apply to `the_title` filter hook by default, while also having the ability to semi-uniquely target items that use `the_title` filter hook with the third parameter.

**It's a simple `boolean` parameter:**

```
/**
 * @param String $title
 * @param Int $object_id
 * @param bool $theme
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function filter_the_title( String $title = null, Int $object_id = null, Bool $theme = false ) {

    if( ! $object_id ){
        return $title;
    }

    if( ! $theme ){
        return $title;
    }

    // your code here...

    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'filter_the_title', 10, 3 );
```

Label the variables however you want. This is what worked for me, and it does exactly what I need it to do. This answer may not be 100% relevant to the question asked, but this is where I arrived while searching to solve this problem. Hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The *global $dontTouch;* solution didn't work for me for some reason. So I simply removed the filter around the menu thus in *header.php*:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); 
add_filter( 'the_title', 'change_title' );
```

And all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
function change_title($title) {
    if( in_the_loop() && !is_archive() ) { // This will skip the menu items and the archive titles
        return $new_title;              
    }    
    return $title;    
}
add_filter('the_title', array($this, 'change_title'), 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post ID to change only the page title:

```
function replace_page_title( $title, $id = null )   {
// Change the post title only if post ID is eg. 123
if ( $id == 123 ) {
$title = "New Title";
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'replace_page_title', 10, 2 );
```